# Arrays.sort seems to be changing my replicated array after replication in Java. Why would this happen?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the code i used.
When i run this code, the names will sort but the marks will not change. I changed the output to troubleshoot and found that tempNames is also sorting alphabetically, even though the "sorting code" is after i made this duplicate array, and the sort does not refer to this array. This means that the marks order will not change. Is there any reason as to why the duplicated array would also change if i change the original one?

```
public void alphabeticalOrder()
{
    String[] namesTemp = names;
    int[] marksTemp = marks;
    Arrays.sort(names);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < namesTemp.length; j++)
        {
            if (names[i].equals(namesTemp[j]))
            {
                marks[i] = marksTemp[j];
            }
        }
    }
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        output += namesTemp[i] + " ";
        //Usually: output += names[i] + " " + marks[i]
          The above change was made to troubleshoot
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The output is the array in alphabetical order, even though i am outputting the original array which is not in alphabetical order.

Here is my original variables i used.

```
names = new String[]
        {
            "James", "Andrew", "Betty", "Kevin", "Dave", "Clarise"
        };
        marks = new int[]
        {
            20, 100, 97, 43, 78, 25
        };
```

the output is Andrew Betty Clarise Dave James Kevin .

Comment: Note: `String[] namesTemp = names` does not create a new array, or a copy in any form. They're both a reference to the same array, you'll need to invoke `new` to create a different array and fill it with what you want

Comment: `String[] namesTemp = names;` doesn't copy an array.  You just have two variables that have the *same* array as their value now.